# sql select multiple rows totals into one row per account_ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My goal is to get all 3 lines in one row.
I am trying to only get back 1 lines.

> ```
> select br_data.acct_id ,
> bs_accts.acct_num, 
> case br_data.recmethod
> when 1 then count(br_data.recmethod) 
> else 0 end as "Open", 
> case br_data.recmethod
> when 2 then count(br_data.recmethod) 
> else 0 end as "Closed", 
> case br_data.recmethod
> when 0 then count(br_data.recmethod)
> else 0 as "Suspended"
> from br_data , bs_accts
> where  br_data.acct_id = bs_accts.acct_id
> and br_data.acct_id = '427'
> group by br_data.acct_id , bs_accts.acct_num  , br_data.recmethod
> order by br_data.acct_id
> ```

Current results:

> ```
> acct_id   acct_num      open    closed     suspended
> 427   0060-1537100-OLD    0         0        376818
> 427   0060-1537100-OLD    2279474   0          0
> 427   0060-1537100-OLD    0        82675       0
> ```

Desired Result:

> ```
> acct_id   acct_num         open    closed     suspended
> 427   0060-1537100-OLD    2279474   82675      376818
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove `br_data.recmethod` from your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    bd.acct_id,
    ba.acct_num,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bd.recmethod = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Open],
    SUM(CASE WHEN bd.recmethod = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Closed],
    SUM(CASE WHEN bd.recmethod = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Suspended]
FROM br_data bd
INNER JOIN bs_accts ba
    ON ba.acct_id = bs.acct_id
WHERE
    bd.acct_id = '427' -- You may want to remove the quotes if this column is of INT type
GROUP BY
    bd.acct_id, bs.acct_num
ORDER BY bd.acct_id
```

---

NOTES

1. [Avoid using old-style `JOIN` syntax.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)
2. You may want to remove the quotation marks on `427` if `ba.account_id` is of `INT` data type.
3. Use alias and use `[]` to enclose your column names.